# Golang language, combine some fields of anonymous structure?

Tags: go, struct, embedding

Database entities, retention and data mapping.

```
type User struct{
        UserId int
        Org   int 
        Name string
        Password string
        Sex int 
        Age  int 
        Avatar string
 }
type Address struct{
     AddressId int 
     UserId int 
     Province int
     City int 
     District int
     Address int 
     Description string
}
```

In DAO, I want to combine, cut, and expand the entity structure...
for example：

```
      type UserInfo struct{
           User
           []Address
       }
```

But the anonymous structure is embedded and can only be quoted in its entirety. How can I quote some fields?

```
    type UserInfo struct{
           User
           []Address

           Password string `json:"-"`
           Sex int `json:"-"`
           Age  int `json:"-"`
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't "quote" some fields. You may embed (or use a regular field) of `User`, or if you don't need all its fields, just explicitly list the needed ones.

Don't be afraid to repeat 3 fields. [Quoting Sandi Metz:](https://sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction)

> Duplication is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction.

If you need "too many" fields and you do want to avoid duplicates, you may put those fields into another struct, and have that embedded both in `User` and in `UserInfo`:

```
type BaseUser struct {
    Password string `json:"-"`
    Sex      int    `json:"-"`
    Age      int    `json:"-"`
}

type User struct {
    BaseUser

    UserId int
    Org    int
    Name   string
    Avatar string
}

type UserInfo struct {
    BaseUser
    Addresses []Address
}
```

Note that you may choose to use a struct tag when embedding `BaseUser` to exclude it from JSON marshalling instead of marking all of `BaseUser`'s fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
type UserInfo struct{
    User
    Addresses []Address

    Password string `json:"-"`
           Sex int `json:"-"`
           Age  int `json:"-"`
       }
```

Comment: Too many fields...